# dao database classes are not supported for win64 platforms in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ocx

I have converted one of our existing VC++ project from VS 6.0 to VS 2010 to build the application in WIN 64 to work on Windows 7 machine. (I tried to register the OCX file in Windows 7 in WOW64 as well. but it throws an exception "Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems.... ").

Everything is converted and having one exception.
"dao database classes are not supported for win64 platforms"

In my project, it is not using any database. 
Can I remove the header file causing this problem? If yes, Please tell me how to delete header file.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the includes of afxdao.h or dbdao.h in your project. Most of the time you can find those in stdafx.h.

Comment: Hi schlzber, The header file afxdao.h is throwing this exception. How can I delete this one from solution?

Comment: You can remove them. If you get errors afterwards check the corresponding places and remove that code as well. Only code that uses DAO should fail compiling so it shouldn't be in conflict with what you want to achieve.